# How to use value generated by GENERATE_UNIQUE() function as foreign key?

Tags: sql, db2

I trying to implement the example from this manual [Generating Unique Values in DB2 Universal Database](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0205pilaka/0205pilaka2.html) but encountered the following problem.

I've two tables,

```
CREATE TABLE PC_LIST (
        PC_ID CHAR(13) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL, 
        PC_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 

        PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

And second table

```
CREATE TABLE PC_DATA (
        ID CHAR(13) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL, 
        PC_ID CHAR(13) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL, 
        PC_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 

        PRIMARY KEY (ID),
        FOREIGN KEY (PC_ID) REFERENCES PC_LIST(PC_ID)
);
```

I add records to first table `PC_LIST` without any issues, and use inside `INSERT` query `GENERATE_UNIQUE()` function, everything works fine.
When I try to add a record to the second table and copy a value from `PC_LIST.PC_ID` as is I get an error `Value "20150408131401000109000000  " is too long..`
When I added a cast like following: `CAST('20150408131401000109000000' AS CHAR(13) FOR BIT DATA)` I get an error that `The INSERT or UPDATE value of the FOREIGN KEY is not equal to any value of the parent key of the parent table`.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

UPDATE: 
This code I use to insert data in `PC_DATA`

```
INSERT INTO PC_DATA 
(
    ID,
    PC_ID, 
    PC_NAME

) VALUES (GENERATE_UNIQUE(), CAST('20150408131401000109000000' AS CHAR(13) FOR BIT DATA) ,'anatoly-pc');
```

Of course that `PC_ID` I've taken from `PC_LIST` table where it exists.

Comment: Show the **actual** code that does the insert into `PC_DATA`.

Comment: Where do you get this `'20150408131401000109000000'`? Binary (`FOR BIT DATA`) string literals usually look like `x'20150408131401000109000000'` -- note the "x".

Comment: I browse data by using SQL explorer inside RAD and it shows this column's value without `x`.

Comment: @mustaccio, I've added `x` at the beginning of a string and it works like a charm. Now my question how to provide it's value when I use `PreparedStatement`? Should I write something like this `x?` and then `setString(1,'20150408131401000109000000')` or it won't work?

Comment: No, you treat it as a binary (`byte[]`) type in Java and bind to the parameter marker as usual.