# How to convert GENERATE_UNIQUE() value to readable format from byte[] and then back to byte[]

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, db2-luw

I use in my application [GENERATE_UNIQUE()](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0205pilaka/0205pilaka2.html) to create IDs. 
When I create a POJO object from a table row I use `rs.getBytes("ID")` and when I write it back to table I use `ps.setBytes(object.getID)`.  According to comments to this question: [How to use value generated by GENERATE_UNIQUE() function as foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516596/how-to-use-value-generated-by-generate-unique-function-as-foreign-key)

But during the POJO lifecycle I need a `String` representation of an ID. 
I can maintain second property to store ID as a `String` but looking for a solution where I can convert from `byte[]` to `String` and back without loosing data.
I tried the following code in various variations but `byte[]` array which I get back isn't the same as an initial `byte[]` array.

```
            byte[] result = rs.getBytes("ID");
            String test = result.toString();
            byte[] test1 = test.getBytes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get my answer here: [Java Byte Array to String to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684665/java-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html

`static byte[] parseBase64Binary(String lexicalXSDBase64Binary)`

and

`static String  printBase64Binary(byte[] val)`